# Flutter Web / There is a problem with firebase Auth status management

Tags: firebase, flutter, web, firebase-authentication

I'm using flutter web and firebase.
I'm using firebase Auth's email authentication, and there are two problems.

1. When refresh the web, authentication is disconnected.
2. Sometimes there is a problem of falling into infinite loading when sign in after web refresh (I think it was caused by the above problem.)

I used almost the same code that I made in the previous app, and when I run it on the app, it works fine.

pubspec.yaml

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_core: ^0.5.0 
  firebase_auth: ^0.18.0 
  cloud_firestore: ^0.14.0 
  firebase_storage: ^4.0.0 
  flutter_web_frame: ^0.0.2 #Web size
  get: ^3.3.0
  provider: ^4.3.3
  google_sign_in: ^4.5.9
```

index.html

```
</script>

<script src = "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.22.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-storage.js"></script>

<script>

  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: ,
    authDomain: ,
    projectId: ,
    storageBucket: ,
    messagingSenderId: ,
    appId: ,
    measurementId: 
  };

  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.getAnalytics(app);

</script>
```

This is part of my authentication code.

firebase_auth_state.dart

```
enum FirebaseAuthStatus { signout, progress, signin }

class FirebaseAuthState extends ChangeNotifier {
  FirebaseAuthStatus _firebaseAuthStatus = FirebaseAuthStatus.progress;
  FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  User _firebaseUser;
        
  //check user state
  void watchAuthChange() {
    _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges().listen((firebaseUser) {
      //when first
      if (firebaseUser == null && _firebaseUser == null) {
          changeFirebaseAuthStatus();

        return;
        //firebaseUser update
      } else if (firebaseUser != _firebaseUser) {
        _firebaseUser = firebaseUser;
        //auth state change check
        changeFirebaseAuthStatus();
      }
    });
  }

  void changeFirebaseAuthStatus([FirebaseAuthStatus firebaseAuthStatus]) {
    if (firebaseAuthStatus != null) {
      _firebaseAuthStatus = firebaseAuthStatus;
    } else {
      if (_firebaseUser != null) {
        _firebaseAuthStatus = FirebaseAuthStatus.signin;
      } else {
        _firebaseAuthStatus = FirebaseAuthStatus.signout;
      }
    }

    notifyListeners();
  }    
}
```

And in main.dart, sign in or sign out according to the authentication status.

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  FirebaseAuthState _firebaseAuthState = FirebaseAuthState();

  //current auth state
  Widget _currentWidget;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _firebaseAuthState.watchAuthChange();

    return 
    .
    .
    .

            home: Consumer<FirebaseAuthState>(
              builder: (BuildContext context, FirebaseAuthState firebaseAuthState,
                  Widget child) {
                switch (firebaseAuthState.firebaseAuthStatus) {
                  case FirebaseAuthStatus.signout:
                    _clearUserModel(context);
                    _currentWidget = AuthScreen();
                    break;

                  case FirebaseAuthStatus.signin:
                    _initUserModel(firebaseAuthState, context);
                    _currentWidget = HomeScreen();
                    break;

                  default:
                    _currentWidget = CustomLoading();
                    break;
                }

                return AnimatedSwitcher(
                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                  child: _currentWidget,
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        );
      },

    );
  }

  //userModel update
  _initUserModel(FirebaseAuthState firebaseAuthState, BuildContext context) {
    UserModelState userModelState =
    Provider.of<UserModelState>(context, listen: false);

    // if (userModelState.currentStreamSub == null) {
    userModelState.currentStreamSub = userNetworkRepo
        .getUserModelStream(firebaseAuthState.firebaseUser.uid)
        .listen((userModel) {
      userModelState.userModel = userModel;

      print('userModel: ${userModel.username} , ${userModel.userKey}');
    });
  }

  _clearUserModel(BuildContext context) {
    UserModelState userModelState =
    Provider.of<UserModelState>(context, listen: false);
    userModelState.clear();
  }
}
```

The biggest problem is that sometimes I can't signIn well.
May I know the cause and solution of this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/3356) with firebase_auth plugin. A workaround for this issue is force reauthentication on page reload as mentioned on this [comment](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/3356#issuecomment-680876366).

Using this code should check for existing auth instance on the session.

```dart
/// Force check for existing users
Future<void>forceAuthInit()async{
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().first;
}
```